# Android set soft input mode with javascript/java bridge outside onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want most of my pages to remain still and the android keyboard to go on top of them, so in **AndroidManifest.xml** I have

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

On one particular page I want the keyboard to push up the content, triggered by a javascript/java bridge in a webview, hence the JavaScriptFunctions class. The toast is purely there to text the interface is working (the toast does appear). `pushKeyboard()` is called from the javascript inside the webview.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    .
    .
    public static Context cont;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptFunctions(), "AndroidNative");
        cont = MainActivity.this;

        // this "works", but is useless because it changes the soft input for the whole application:
        //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }

    public class JavaScriptFunctions {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void pushKeyboard() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Balls.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // MainActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); // This gives error "can't reference non-static method from static context"
            ((Activity)getApplicationContext()).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); // fails
            // getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); // fails
            //((Activity)cont).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); // extreme failure

        }
    }
}
```

The monitor shows this error:

**W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

Inside onCreate(), the code does indeed set the soft input mode, but I can't get it working from inside JavaScriptFunctions. I've tried many variations, including creating a Context in MainActivity.
How do I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Side rant-  `public static Context cont; cont = MainActivity.this;`
  NEVER DO THIS.  This is a memory leak.  If you need a global Context, use the Application Context and make a static to hold the application context.  Do not hold static references to an Activity.

As for your error-  you need to call UI effecting functions from the UI thread.  If you can't (due to being called from somewhere odd via JS) call pushKeyboard on the main thread, then post a message to the handler and make the UI effecting calls there.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533798/346613), which I think is pretty much what Gabe was saying. Any comments or improvements welcome.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    .
    .

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptFunctions(), "AndroidNative");

    }

    public void resize() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
            }
        });
    }

    public class JavaScriptFunctions {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void pushKeyboard() {
            resize();
        }
    }
}
```